# TomEE Config Problems , jndi.properties, NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, server, config, jndi, apache-tomee

as the title already shows, I am stuck with my server configuration. Goal is to have a class which will be acting as publisher and lots of subscribers to a specific topic. I am running on TomEE because the whole environment is on tomcat, and TomEE delivers the JMS API.

Now to the code:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [TopicConnectionFactory] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [TopicConnectionFactory].
```

that is the excpetion I get when I move to the .jsp file inside my browser which calls the method.

PUBLISHER:

```
public void doIt(){

    String _topicName = null;
    Context _jndiContext = null;
    TopicConnectionFactory _topicConnectionFactory=null;
    TopicConnection _topicConnection = null;
    TopicSession _topicSession= null;
    Topic _topic = null;
    TopicPublisher _topicPublisher = null;
    TextMessage _textMessage = null;
    _topicName = "Events";
    try {
        _jndiContext = new InitialContext();
        _topicConnectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) _jndiContext.lookup("TopicConnectionFactory");
        _topic = (Topic) _jndiContext.lookup(_topicName);
        _topicConnection = _topicConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
        _topicSession = _topicConnection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        _topicPublisher = _topicSession.createPublisher(_topic);
        for(int i = 0; i < 1500; i++){
            _textMessage = _topicSession.createTextMessage("This i message: "+ i);
            _topicPublisher.publish(_textMessage);
        }
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(_topicConnection != null){
            try{
                _topicConnection.close();
            }catch(JMSException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

doIt() is called inside the .jsp

SUBSCRIBER

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    String _topicName = null;
    Context _jndiContext = null;
    TopicConnectionFactory _topicConnectionFactory = null;
    TopicConnection _topicConnection = null;
    TopicSession _topicSession = null;
    Topic _topic = null;
    TopicSubscriber _topicSubscriber = null;
    TextListener _topicListener = null;
    TextMessage _textMessage = null;

    _topicName = "Events";
    try {
        _jndiContext = new InitialContext();
        _topicConnectionFactory =(TopicConnectionFactory) _jndiContext.lookup("TopicConnectionFactory");
        _topic = (Topic) _jndiContext.lookup(_topicName);
        _topicConnection = _topicConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
        _topicSession = _topicConnection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        _topicSubscriber = _topicSession.createSubscriber(_topic);
        _topicListener = new TextListener();
        _topicSubscriber.setMessageListener(_topicListener);
        _topicConnection.start();

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(_topicConnection != null){
            try{
                _topicConnection.close();
            }catch(JMSException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

AND last but not least the jndi.properties file which is inside src folder...so inside build path

```
java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url = tcp://localhost:8080
connectionFactoryNames = ConnectionFactory, queueConnectionFactory, TopicConnectionFactory
queue.MyQueue = example.MyQueue
topic.MyTopic = Events
```

This is copied because I have absolutely no idea how to accomplish this lookup mechanism. If you see anything wrong, please, correct it accordingly!

Comment: Ignore the content which is produced inside the for loop...it is only for testing if the messages will be transferred

Answer (score 0):

In case you defined TopicConnectionFactory in `tomee.xml` the name is likely: 
`openejb:Resource/TopicConnectionFactory`